# Replace html tag with some text

Tags: javascript

I want to replace long sequences of "`<br>`" with some text, to solve a problem with people posting long texts in my forum.

I specifically want to replace 
"`<br>`
`<br>`
`<br>`"
(3 br in a row)
with "`|`"

How do I do that using Javascript?

Comment: This sounds like something that might be best fixed server-side. What software are you using to run the forum?

Comment: You question is vague and gives no proper information. What does `" (3 br in a row) with "|"` mean?

Comment: Javascript has a replace function. What server-side are you using - PHP, Asp.Net, django?

Comment: @harsha 
   br { display: none !important;}

Comment: like this http://i.imgur.com/ve95o.png become http://i.imgur.com/rnD1O.png

@marsha when i using  `code`br { display: none !important;}`code` in css all br in whole page missing

@Cdeez http://i.imgur.com/ns008.png

Sorry, my english isn't good :)

related page [link]http://www.kaskus.co.id/showthread.php?t=15989592&page=439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to achieve that [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FgNHb/1/)

```
 htmlContent.replace(/<br>\s<br>\s<br>/g, "|"); // will replace all 3 br in row (ignoring space)
```